# SGA size not decreasing after reducing memory_target (Oracle 11.2.0.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, memory

I have an Oracle 11.2.0.1 database using dynamic memory allocation with parameter `MEMORY_TARGET`. When I decrease it with SCOPE=BOTH, the size of the SGA doesn't seem to decrease along with it. I have tested this on multiple systems. Here is an example

```
SQL> show parameter memory_target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------------------
memory_target                        big integer 820M
SQL> sho sga

Total System Global Area  855982080 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180544 bytes
Variable Size             520096320 bytes
Database Buffers          327155712 bytes
Redo Buffers                6549504 bytes
SQL> alter system set memory_Target=720M scope=both;

System altered.

SQL> show sga

Total System Global Area  855982080 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180544 bytes
Variable Size             520096320 bytes
Database Buffers          327155712 bytes
Redo Buffers                6549504 bytes
SQL> show parameter memory_target;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------------------
memory_target                        big integer 720M
SQL>
```

However, after I bounce the instance, the SGA seems to size itself appropriately.

```
SQL> sho sga

Total System Global Area  751595520 bytes
Fixed Size                  2179536 bytes
Variable Size             415239728 bytes
Database Buffers          327155712 bytes
Redo Buffers                7020544 bytes
SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `show sga` for querying the current SGA size.

`Total System Global Area` in the output of `show sga` is computed as `select sum(value) from v$sga`, you can easily confirm this by enabling SQL trace.

```
SQL> select * from v$sga;

NAME                      VALUE
-------------------- ----------
Fixed Size              2258040
Variable Size         490736520
Database Buffers      356515840
Redo Buffers            6471680

SQL> select sum(value) from v$sga;

SUM(VALUE)
----------
 855982080
```

This includes `Variable Size`, and that is not the current usage. Use `v$memory_dynamic_components`. For an even more detailed list, use `v$sgastat` and `v$pgastat`, I will not post output of those here.

```
SQL> show parameter memory_target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_target                        big integer 820M

SQL> show sga

Total System Global Area  855982080 bytes
Fixed Size                  2258040 bytes
Variable Size             494930824 bytes
Database Buffers          352321536 bytes
Redo Buffers                6471680 bytes

SQL> select component, current_size, min_size, max_size from v$memory_dynamic_components;

COMPONENT                 CURRENT_SIZE   MIN_SIZE   MAX_SIZE
------------------------- ------------ ---------- ----------
shared pool                  134217728  130023424  134217728
large pool                     8388608    8388608   71303168
java pool                      4194304    4194304    4194304
streams pool                   4194304          0    4194304
SGA Target                   515899392  515899392  515899392
DEFAULT buffer cache         352321536  289406976  352321536
KEEP buffer cache                    0          0          0
RECYCLE buffer cache                 0          0          0
DEFAULT 2K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 4K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 8K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 16K buffer cache             0          0          0
DEFAULT 32K buffer cache             0          0          0
Shared IO Pool                       0          0          0
PGA Target                   343932928  343932928  343932928
ASM Buffer Cache                     0          0          0
```

Now, decreasing `memory_target` (and that is **not** necessarily the SGA).

```
SQL> alter system set memory_target=720M scope=memory;

System altered.

SQL> show parameter memory_target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_target                        big integer 720M

SQL> show sga

Total System Global Area  855982080 bytes
Fixed Size                  2258040 bytes
Variable Size             494930824 bytes
Database Buffers          352321536 bytes
Redo Buffers                6471680 bytes
```

`show sga` still shows the old values.

```
SQL> select component, current_size, min_size, max_size from v$memory_dynamic_components;

COMPONENT                 CURRENT_SIZE   MIN_SIZE   MAX_SIZE
------------------------- ------------ ---------- ----------
shared pool                  134217728  130023424  134217728
large pool                     8388608    8388608   71303168
java pool                      4194304    4194304    4194304
streams pool                   4194304          0    4194304
SGA Target                   515899392  515899392  515899392
DEFAULT buffer cache         352321536  289406976  352321536
KEEP buffer cache                    0          0          0
RECYCLE buffer cache                 0          0          0
DEFAULT 2K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 4K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 8K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 16K buffer cache             0          0          0
DEFAULT 32K buffer cache             0          0          0
Shared IO Pool                       0          0          0
PGA Target                   239075328  239075328  343932928
ASM Buffer Cache                     0          0          0
```

Notice how `SGA Target` did not change at all. Instead, `PGA Target` was decreased. Decreasing it further:

```
SQL> alter system set memory_target=420M scope=memory;

System altered.

SQL> show sga

Total System Global Area  855982080 bytes
Fixed Size                  2258040 bytes
Variable Size             629148552 bytes
Database Buffers          218103808 bytes
Redo Buffers                6471680 bytes
```

Notice how `Variable Size` has changed, but `Total System Global Area` has not.

```
SQL> select component, current_size, min_size, max_size from v$memory_dynamic_components;

COMPONENT                 CURRENT_SIZE   MIN_SIZE   MAX_SIZE
------------------------- ------------ ---------- ----------
shared pool                  134217728  130023424  134217728
large pool                     8388608    8388608   71303168
java pool                      4194304    4194304    4194304
streams pool                   4194304          0    4194304
SGA Target                   381681664  381681664  515899392
DEFAULT buffer cache         218103808  218103808  352321536
KEEP buffer cache                    0          0          0
RECYCLE buffer cache                 0          0          0
DEFAULT 2K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 4K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 8K buffer cache              0          0          0
DEFAULT 16K buffer cache             0          0          0
DEFAULT 32K buffer cache             0          0          0
Shared IO Pool                       0          0          0
PGA Target                    58720256   58720256  343932928
ASM Buffer Cache                     0          0          0
```

`Variable Size` is there because, `memory_max_size` and `sga_max_size` was computed from `memory_target` at instance startup time.

```
SQL> show parameter memory_max

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_max_target                    big integer 820M
SQL> show parameter sga_max

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sga_max_size                         big integer 820M
```

This allows us to increase SGA back to that point. But those you can not change dynamically:

```
SQL> alter system set memory_max_target=420M scope=memory;
alter system set memory_max_target=420M scope=memory
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified


SQL> alter system set sga_max_size=420M scope=memory;
alter system set sga_max_size=420M scope=memory
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified


SQL> alter system set memory_max_target=920M scope=memory;
alter system set memory_max_target=920M scope=memory
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified


SQL> alter system set sga_max_size=920M scope=memory;
alter system set sga_max_size=920M scope=memory
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified
```